# How to preview texture without lighting

Tags: texturing, uv, light

A lot of the time when I'm UV Unwrapping and Texturing, the shadows get in the way of seeing the texture properly.

How can I display my textures on my model without lighting.

Comment: Which render engine are you using?

Comment: @Denis I'm such a scrub, I use whatever the default startup file uses when you select "Textures" mode from the 3d view's render mode.

Comment: then you are in Blender Internal render engine, the answer for your problem is below.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please accept it. If it didn't please say so, so that we can figure out what you need to fix your problem.

Comment: I haven't tested yet, will do before much longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the Blender Internal rendering engine, you can turn off shading on a material using the shadeless checkbox.

[image: Effects of the shadeless checkbox]

Please note that I have GLSL shading enabled. You can find it in the N panel int the 3D view. It's default value is Multitexture.

[image: GLSL shading drop down]